# Where is the \matrix command?

Tags: matrices, mathjax

From what I can see, `\matrix` was a TeX command, but I cannot seem to find documentation on it.

[It works in MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=matrix), so I wonder if it can be used in LaTeX.

ie this is valid MathJax:

```
$$
\left[
\matrix
{
newx.x&newy.x&newz.x \\
newx.y&newy.y&newz.y \\
newx.z&newy.z&newz.z    
}
\right]
$$
```

As can be seen on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53368/rotation-matrices-using-a-change-of-basis-approach/53370).

In my LaTeX editor (which uses MiKTeX underneath), I have to use `\begin{matrix} .. \end{matrix}`, so I'm wondering what happened to the `\matrix` command.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: I would upvote purely for the `doom` avatar. But I've reached the limit cap. Wait, is that doom or wolfenstein?

Comment: @Seamus: `doom` and I upped for you :)

Comment: Doom is 18 years old: 1993! OH wow. Makes me feel old...

Comment: MathJaX is not a reliable guide as to what is available in "standard" LaTeX.  It "loads" several packages (or, rather, simulates loading several packages) that are considered "standard" (in that many mathematicians use them).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In addition to some already provided, here are a number of ways of creating matrices in LaTeX. Using

- an `array` structure to place items in a rigid row/column environment;
- `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}` from the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), which allows you to specify the matrix delimiters yourself (using `\left` and `\right`);
- `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `Bmatrix`, `vmatrix` and `Vmatrix` variations to the above (also from `amsmath`) to fix the delimiters to `( )`, `[ ]`, `{ }`, `| |`, and `|| ||`, respectively;
- `\bordermatrix{...}` which is a TeX command and will specify row and column indicies;
- [`\kbordermatrix{...}`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) which is similar to the above, but provides more flexibility;
- the [`blkarray` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) and the associated `blockarray` and `block` environments to construct your matrix.

Here is an example file showing some of the different styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}% http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{lc}
  \verb|array| & \left(\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{array}\right) \\[15pt]
  \verb|matrix| & \left(\begin{matrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{matrix}\right) \\[15pt]
  \verb|pmatrix| & \begin{pmatrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{pmatrix} \\[15pt]
  \verb|bmatrix| & \begin{bmatrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{bmatrix} \\[15pt]
  \verb|Bmatrix| & \begin{Bmatrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{Bmatrix} \\[15pt]
  \verb|vmatrix| & \begin{vmatrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{vmatrix} \\[15pt]
  \verb|Vmatrix| & \begin{Vmatrix}
                    a & b & c \\
                    d & e & f \\
                    g & h & i
                  \end{Vmatrix} \\[15pt]
  \verb|bordermatrix| & \bordermatrix{\text{corner}&c_1&c_2&\ldots &c_n\cr
                r_1&a_{11} &  0  & \ldots & a_{1n}\cr
                r_2& 0  &  a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n}\cr
                r_3& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\cr
                r_4& 0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}} \\[15pt]
  \verb|kbordermatrix| & \kbordermatrix{\text{corner}&c_1&c_2&\ldots &c_n\cr
                r_1&a_{11} &  0  & \ldots & a_{1n}\cr
                r_2& 0  &  a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n}\cr
                r_3& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\cr
                r_4& 0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}} \\[25pt]
  \verb|blkarray| & \begin{blockarray}{[cc]c\}}
                11 & 22 & 33 \\
                1 & 2 & 3 \\
                \begin{block}{(ll)l\}}
                  11 & 22 & 33 \\
                  1 & 2 & 3 \\
                \end{block}
                1 & 2 & 3
                \end{blockarray}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Matrices]

Comment: This is the sort of thorough answer we need more of on this site! well done!

Comment: I second @Seamus. Great answer, Werner! There should be a *Welcome to the Matrix* badge. `=)`

Comment: "Unfortunately, no one can tell you what the matrix is. Except for Werner, he seems to do it pretty well."

Comment: @Werner: if one wants to use `{array}` to do a matrix, it is important to suppress the spurious spaces between the two delimiters and the array by using `\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}`. Also, an interesting package to do complex border matrix is the [blkarray](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray); there are a few examples of use on [this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=blkarray).

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks - I've updated it with your suggestions, including an example in the [`blkarray` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/blkarray/blkarray.pdf).

Comment: Werner, thanks for the GREAT answer! Would you consider adding `qbordermatrix` to your list? :)

Comment: Once we go into [k]bordermatrix and blockarray, it's good to also be aware of `bigdelim` package which works with standard `array`/`matrix` and `multirow` and gives more flexibility.

Comment: Ah yes, the Bordered matrix TeX package, written by professor K. C. Border

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use `\matrix{` but `\begin{matrix}` and `\end{matrix}` are provided by the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 5):

It's strongly recommended to use amsmath's matrix features. However, answering your question: you can find the definition of `\matrix` in `plain.tex`:

```
\def\matrix#1{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
```

Related:

```
\def\pmatrix#1{\left(\matrix{#1}\right)}
```

You can find `plain.tex` by typing on the command prompt

```
kpsewhich plain.tex
```

which gives on a current standard Windows TeX Live installation, for example

```
c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
```

`\matrix` is documented in the TeX book and various other TeX documentation. LaTeX documentation is mostly about the more modern `matrix` environment of amsmath.

Comment: So, why doesn't `\matrix` work in my LaTeX implementation, if its part of TeX?

Comment: @bobobobo: `MathJax` also reports the use of [environments](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/tex.html?highlight=matrix#environments) which includes `amsmath`'s `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`. Not sure what happened to `\matrix{...}`.

Comment: @bobobobo: The quick answer is that "plain TeX" is not plain TeX.  "plain TeX" is an extension of TeX much as LaTeX is and LaTeX is not built on top of "plain TeX".

Answer (score 4):

The command `\matrix` is defined in the LaTeX kernel

```
% latex.ltx, line 4509:
\def\matrix#1{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
\def\pmatrix#1{\left(\matrix{#1}\right)}
```

(the version of LaTeX used is `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`).

Comparing it with `plain.tex`

```
% plain.tex, line 1093:
\def\matrix#1{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
\def\pmatrix#1{\left(\matrix{#1}\right)}
```

we see no difference at all.

The reason is historical: when LaTeX was first issued, it incorporated much of `plain.tex`, in order to ease switch from one to the other. Moreover, the original LaTeX kernel had very basic support for math: in addition to plain TeX structures it only provided `displaymath`, `equation`, `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*`. The `eqnarray` environment and its starred companion were designed as replacement for `eqalignno` and `eqalign` (but not the best replacement).

When `amsmath` came to light (at first named `amslatex`), a problem arose: the original `amstex.tex` plug in for plain.tex used `\matrix ... \endmatrix` which ought to get the LaTeX syntax `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`. There's of course a conflict: a document using `\matrix{...}` as supported by the LaTeX kernel would be at stake if `amsmath` is loaded. Similarly for `\pmatrix{...}` and `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}`.

Indeed `amsmath` has

```
\renewenvironment{matrix}{%
  \matrix@check\matrix\env@matrix
}{%
  \endarray \hskip -\arraycolsep
}
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\newcount\c@MaxMatrixCols \c@MaxMatrixCols=10
\def\matrix@check#1{%
  \@xp\ifx\csname\@currenvir\endcsname#1%
  \else\matrix@error#1%
    \@xp\@gobble
  \fi
}
\def\matrix@error#1{%
  \@amsmath@err{%
Old form `\string#1' should be \string\begin{\@xp\@gobble\string#1}%
  }{%
`\string#1{...}' is old Plain-TeX syntax whose use is
ill-advised in LaTeX.%
  }%
}
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{%
  \left(%
  \matrix@check\pmatrix\env@matrix
}{
  \endmatrix\right)%
}
```

What does this mean? We know that `\begin{foo}` first does some bookkeeping, including defining `\@currenvir` to mean `foo` and then executes `\foo`, so replacing it with the tokens given in the “begin part” at definition time. In the case of `\matrix` and `\pmatrix`, `\matrix@check` is performed; this command checks whether the current environment name matches either `matrix` or `pmatrix`; this will be true if the document has used `\begin{matrix}` or `\begin{pmatrix}`, but false if the plain TeX syntax `\matrix{...}` or `\pmatrix{...}` is used. In the latter case, an error is raised and the argument to `\matrix` or `\pmatrix` is gobbled for allowing to complete the LaTeX run.

This conflict is not really so serious: every document with substantial use of math should load `amsmath` and therefore employ the `\begin{matrix}` or `\begin{pmatrix}` syntax.

By the way, this has a consequence; if one wants to build over `matrix` using “macho programming style”, an environment should not be defined like

```
\newenvironment{foomatrix}
 {<something at the beginning>\matrix}
 {\endmatrix<something at the end>}
```

because this would trigger `\matrix@error`. Instead

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foomatrix}
 {<something at the beginning>\env@matrix}
 {\endmatrix<something at the end>}
\makeatother
```

should be used; for instance, `amsmath` has

```
\newenvironment{bmatrix}{\left[\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right]}
```

---

With MathJax, *both*

```
\matrix{ 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 }
```

and

```
\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}
```

are allowed. The implementation doesn't really “expand” `\begin` like it's done in LaTeX, so it is free to do other tricks.