# Array with labeling columns

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, matrices, arrays

Is there an intelligent way to label (or name) columns in a matrix? I would like to have something like

```
\[M=\left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{array}\right],N=\left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
7 & 8 & 9\\
10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}\right]\]
\[A \ B \ C \ D \ E \ F\]
```

where A, B,..., F are the labels (or rather names) of the first, second, ..., sixth columns, respectively. What I want is to label A be exactly below the first column, label B be below the second column, etc., of course, nicely aligned. So far I have forced some extra spaces before the labels manually, and also experimented with the `\phantom` command.

Comment: Also see: [Where is the \matrix command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command/26447#26447)

Answer (score 13):

The [`kbordermatrix` package](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/LaTeX.shtml) does a neat job in typesetting a matrix with indices. It has a format similar to (La)TeX's `\bordermatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}% http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml
\newcommand{\noindex}{\hspace*{-0.8em}}%
\begin{document}
\[
  M=\kbordermatrix{%
      & A &        & B & C \\
    1 & 1 & \vrule & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 4 & \vrule & 5 & 6
  },\quad
  N=\kbordermatrix{%
    \noindex &  D &        &  E &  F \\
    \noindex &  7 & \vrule &  8 &  9 \\
    \noindex & 10 & \vrule & 11 & 12
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

The vertical alignment with respect to the equation/expression is maintained well.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `blkarray` package for this. It allows you to use `block`s inside an array that can be formatted like independent arrays:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[M=
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\begin{block}{[c|cc]}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray},\quad
N=
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
D & E & F \\
\begin{block}{[c|cc]}
7 & 8 & 9 \\
10 & 11 & 12\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just flip the indexes to the bottom (OP's request).

Comment: Well, on a second thought I don't like the vertical alignment of your solution. The matrix names M and N as well as the separating comma are aligned with the whole array (i.e. with its all three lines).

Comment: @Mats: Are you referring to the case when the column indexes are at the top, or bottom, or both?

Comment: I guess it does not matter where I place the indices. In either case, the equality sign is vertically aligned with the whole \blockarray environment, and not with the individual \block which represents the matrix, without its labelling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the environments of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle , 
    code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle , 
  }

$M = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{c|cc}[first-col,first-row]
  & A & B & C \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 5 & 6 
\end{bNiceArray}$,\qquad
$N = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{c|cc}[first-row]
D & E & F \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
10 & 11 & 12
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]