# Labelling Columns of a Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a 3-by-3 matrix. I want to label the columns as R, E, and D for instance. How can I achieve this in LaTeX? I am using `$$ ... $$` environment for writing this matrix.

Comment: This would help !! -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30791/34618