# aligning a matrix with its label

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Suppose I have the following latex code which draws a matrix within a matrix as follows where the cell (1,2) of the outer matrix is a vector that defines the column labels and the cell (2,1) of the outer matrix is a vector that defines the row labels and the cell (2,2) contains the matrix:

```
\begin{matrix}
 & \begin{matrix}
\cdots & \rho_{ij} & \cdots & \rho_{ik} & \cdots & \gamma_i & \cdots & \gamma_j  & \cdots & \lambda 
\end{matrix}\\ 
\begin{matrix}
\cdots \\ 
\rho_{ij}\\ 
\cdots \\ 
\rho_{ik}\\ 
\cdots \\ 
\gamma_i \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\lambda \\ 
\end{matrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\cdots & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_i \mu_i & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_k \mu_k & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i\\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i & \cdots & -\mu_j & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
```

The problem I have at hand is that the row labels (in cell (2,1)) and the column labels (in cell(1,2)) do not necessarily align with the matrix (in cell (2,2)).

How can I align them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stay true to your implementation, you'll have to use some way of specifying the width of the columns that have differing widths-than-headings. Easiest is to make a box where you find the widest element in the column to get the correct width, and set the heading within that box of said width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand{\mathwd}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$#1$}]{$#2$}}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{matrix}
    &
    \begin{matrix}
      \cdots & \mathwd{b_j\mu_j}{\rho_{ij}} & \cdots & \mathwd{b_k\mu_k}{\rho_{ik}} & \cdots & 
        \mathwd{b_j\mu_j}{\gamma_i} & \cdots & \mathwd{-\mu_j}{\gamma_j} & \cdots & \mathwd{-\mu_i}{\lambda}
    \end{matrix} \\
    \begin{matrix}
      \cdots \\ 
      \rho_{ij}\\ 
      \cdots \\ 
      \rho_{ik}\\ 
      \cdots \\ 
      \gamma_i \\ 
      \cdots \\ 
      \lambda \\ 
    \end{matrix} &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
      \cdots & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_i \mu_i & \cdots & 0 \\ 
      \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
      \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
      \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
      \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_k \mu_k & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i\\ 
      \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
      \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i & \cdots & -\mu_j & \cdots & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Alternative inputs also exist in the form of `bordermatrix`, [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) and [`kbordermatrix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix). See [Array with labeling columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30791/5764).

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
    &
\cdots & \rho_{ij} & \cdots & \rho_{ik} & \cdots & \gamma_i & \cdots & \gamma_j & \cdots & \lambda \\
\cdots  &  \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\rho_{ij}& \cdots & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_i \mu_i & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\rho_{ik} & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\gamma_i & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_k \mu_k & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i\\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\lambda & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i & \cdots & -\mu_j & \cdots & 0
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want the first column (outside the matrix) centered, you have to change slightly the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceArray}[first-row]{c[*{10}{c}]}
    &
\cdots & \rho_{ij} & \cdots & \rho_{ik} & \cdots & \gamma_i & \cdots & \gamma_j & \cdots & \lambda \\
\cdots  &  \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\rho_{ij}& \cdots & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_i \mu_i & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\rho_{ik} & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\gamma_i & \cdots & b_j \mu_j & \cdots & b_k \mu_k & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i\\ 
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
\lambda & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & -\mu_i & \cdots & -\mu_j & \cdots & 0
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]