# Can I make a matrix from just a parts of the cells?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, matrices, brackets, delimiters

Can I make a matrix from just a parts of the cells?
i.e. not all the cells just some of it,  like here:

[image]

It possible to make something like this?

Thank you!!

P.S. I'm using LyX.

Comment: Of course it is possible :-). At least drawing it as `tikz` picture or use package `nicematrix`, etc. What you try so far?

Comment: I'm using LyX - So I tried to put it at some cells and I didn't succeed this why I'm asking here...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with LyX.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks! but at TikZ it very complicated, no?

Comment: `blkarray` perhaps (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/array-with-labeling-columns/30792#30792, there are more examples on the site). You would have to write the code manually though, I don't think LyX has implemented support for `blkarray`.

Comment: @Zarko, do you know how to write this array (above) at nicematrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `blkarray` package makes it particularly easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{*{5}{c}} 
1 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 52 \\
\begin{block}{c[ccc]c}
3 & 17 & 9 & 9 & 1 \\
 12 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 5 \\
\end{block}
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,last-row,last-col]
1  & 7  & 8 & 6 & 52 \\
3  & 17 & 9 & 9 & 1 \\
12 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 5 \\
1  & 2  & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

With `nicematrix`, you have also tools to put delimiters exactly where you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
1  & 7  & 8 & 6 & 52 \\
3  & 17 & 9 & 9 & 1 \\
12 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 5 \\
1  & 2  & 2 & 4 & 5
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-2}{3-3}]
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]