# How to label an array?

Tags: labels, arrays

How do I label an array?    The label can be anywhere on the right side.  I can't find a \label in the array documentation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "label"? Are you just interested in marking a specific row? Or are you truly talking about a `\label` so you can `\ref`erence it later?

Comment: I mean in the way you label an equation

Comment: Is the `array` in question associated with a counter variable?

Comment: How about `\begin{equation} \left[\begin{array}{..} ... \end{array}\right] \end{equation}`?

Comment: May this help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/array-with-labeling-columns

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear, what you like to have. I guess, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

Using @Werner comment for staring point, the MWE for above array is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "eqref"

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:array}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8 & 9
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
See array \eqref{eq:array} ...
\end{document}
```

in the case, that your array present an matrix, then you could use `bmatrix` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "bmatrix" and "eqref"

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:array}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8 & 9
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
See array \eqref{eq:array} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]