# Using "found" code to typeset augmented matrices, want [] instead of ()

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, brackets, delimiters

Here's a minimal example of what I'm doing presently:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
      \hskip -\arraycolsep
      \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}[ccc:c]
  1&2&3&0 \\
  4&5&6&0 \\
  7&8&9&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image: Present output (parens)]

I'd prefer if the left and right brackets on the matrix were square brackets instead of parentheses.

Is there an easy way to make such a change?

Comment: A excellent summary of matricies is in this answer: [where is the matrix command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command/26447#26447)

Comment: Nice. That is a good summary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy.  Change `pmatrix` to `bmatrix`:

[image]

See `amsmath` documentation for other kinds of matrices, like `vmatrix`, `Vmatrix`, etc

Comment: Thanks @Boris! That works great! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: or look at mathmode.pdf (26.6 Matrix environments) with `texdoc mathmode.pdf`