# Write elements above and right outside the matrix

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

I found writing matrix's code is a boring work. There is one, you can see in pic below.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: This would be a good start: [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Comment: Thanks. I found only the `blkarray` package may provide help (Was I wrong?) from your links. But there is a large **warning** in its PDF document's. Can I use it without leading to any incompatibility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely possible when using the [`blkarray` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray). Here's a mock-up with some index styling (in `\scriptsize`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\newcommand{\matindex}[1]{\mbox{\scriptsize#1}}% Matrix index
\begin{document}
\[
  A=\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
    \matindex{1} & \matindex{2} & \\
    \begin{block}{(cc)c}
      a & b & \matindex{3} \\
      c & d & \matindex{4} \\
      e & f &   \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

This would also be doable using a plain `array`, but would require additional vertical alignment/compensation, perhaps removing some of the code readability that exists via `blkarray`.

Comment: Hi Werner. I found your answer helpful. How does one selectively adjust the spacing between the block and the elements exterior to the block?

Comment: @user001: Just on one side, or both (right and above)?

Comment: Preferably I would like to adjust the spacing between the top elements and the matrix and the right elements and the matrix to different extents.

Answer (score 3):

The package `nicematrix` has tools to address that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
  \NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,code-for-last-row=\scriptstyle}
  A=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col=3]
      1 & 2 & \\
      a & b & 3 \\
      c & d & 4 \\
      e & f &   \\
  \end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]