# How to create a matrix with rows and columns labeled (at the right side)?

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

I would like to create a matrix with rows and columns being labeled. I would
like the matrix elements to be right aligned, the row labels being displayed to
the right of the matrix, and the column labels above the matrix. I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
% does work:
$\bordermatrix{%
 & 1 & 2 \cr
1 & x1 & x2 \cr
2 & x3 & x423 \cr
3 & x5 & x6
}$
% does not work (see error below):
% $\bordermatrix*{%
%   x1&x2&1\cr
%   x3&x4&2\cr
%   x5&x6&3\cr
%   1&2 6 }$
\end{document}

% ERROR: Misplaced alignment tab character &.

% --- TeX said ---
% l.17   x1&
%           x2&1\cr
% --- HELP ---
% The special character &, which should be used only to separate items
% in an array or tabular environment, appeared in ordinary text. You
% probably meant to type \&.
```

To get at least the row labels displayed at the correct side of the matrix, I
wanted to use the starred version of `\bordermatrix`, but that did not work (as
opposed to given in Voss's mathmode guide). Also, the matrix entries are not
right aligned. How can I create such a matrix? Is there a way to do this with `amsmath`?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the link by Werner, a minimal example is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\newcommand{\matindex}[1]{\mbox{\scriptsize#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
  A=\begin{blockarray}{rrl}
    \matindex{1} & \matindex{2} & \\
    \begin{block}{(rr)l}
      \,100 & b\phantom{\,} & \matindex{row 1} \\
      2 & 12 & \matindex{row 2} \\
      e & f &  \matindex{ABDC} \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

It's just a quick hack to get a bit more horizontal space between the parentheses and the matrix entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Write elements above and right outside the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45475/5764). And then there's a more generic answer in [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Comment: I looked quite hard, but didn't find that post. Thanks, Werner. I posted a minimal example above. I had to use some ugly tricks to get a nicer spacing. Maybe that can be improved.

Comment: You don't have to place `\,` in a `\phantom`, since it is only white space anyway. I've added an answer to reflect some possible spacing alternatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way to insert your matrix indices on the top (for columns) and right (for rows):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\newcommand{\matindex}[1]{\mbox{\scriptsize#1}}% Matrix index
\begin{document}
\[
  A=\begin{blockarray}{c@{\hspace{5pt}}rr@{\hspace{5pt}}cl}
    & \matindex{1} & \matindex{2} & & \\
    \begin{block}{(c@{\hspace{5pt}}rr@{\hspace{5pt}}c)l}
      & 100 &  b & & \matindex{row 1} \\
      &   2 & 12 & & \matindex{row 2} \\
      &   e &  f & & \matindex{ABDC} \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

To improve the spacing between the matrix and the surrounding braces, insert an extra column on either side. Additionally, specify the exact column gap using the `@{...}` specifier. In the above example, two "dummy" `c`entered columns were added with an `\hspace{5pt}` gap.

Comment: How to replace parenthesise with brackets `[]` in the matrix?

Comment: @Rasoul: Replace the use of `(`...`)` inside the inner `block` with `[`...`]`.

Comment: Sorry, If i want to insert the matrix in \underbrace{}{}, there is a way to fix the distance?

Comment: I mean, the brace is very distance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = $\small$ , 
    code-for-last-col = $\small$ 
  }

$A = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col,margin,r]
 1  & 2 \\
100 & b  & \text{row } 1 \\
  2 & 12 & \text{row } 2 \\
  e & f  & \text{ABDC}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]