# Matrix with rows and columns labeled

Tags: matrices

It is trivial to make matrices like so:

```
\begin {pmatrix} s & t & a \\ c & k & x \\ cha & n & ge \end {pmatrix}
```

It is not so trivial to impose labels on the rows and columns as done in page 410 [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf). I would like to do this. For example, the matrix in 11.6:

[image]

---

Note: I am aware of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46722/how-to-create-a-matrix-with-rows-and-columns-labeled-at-the-right-side) but this is *not* what I'm looking for.

Comment: You should look at [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764) There you'll see what you're looking for, including using [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are three different option using `\bordermatrix`, [`kbordermatrix`](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) and [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,blkarray}

\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{P} = 
    \bordermatrix{ & H & Y & D \cr
      H & .8 & .2 & .0 \cr
      Y & .3 & .4 & .3 \cr
      D & .2 & .1 & .7 } \qquad
  \mathbf{P} = 
    \kbordermatrix{ & H & Y & D \\
      H & .8 & .2 & .0 \\
      Y & .3 & .4 & .3 \\
      D & .2 & .1 & .7 } \qquad
  \mathbf{P} = 
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        & H & Y & D \\
      \begin{block}{c(ccc)}
        H & .8 & .2 & .0 \\
        Y & .3 & .4 & .3 \\
        D & .2 & .1 & .7 \\
      \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: See this for more options with border: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/157031

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools to address that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle ,
    code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle 
  }

\[
\mathbf{P} = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
  & H  & Y  & D \\
H & .8 & .2 & .0 \\
Y & .3 & .4 & .3 \\
D & .2 & .1 & .7 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]