# How can I list the X and Y values on the outside of a 6x6 matrix, as well as list the axis names outside of them? (see image)

Tags: matrices, axis

Current 6x6 matrix.

```
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
     1&2&3&4&5&6\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

[image: What I am trying to recreate]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters helps. Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223501/matrix-with-rows-and-columns-labeled