# problem in alignment of arrays

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0\longrightarrow S
\xrightarrow{
\begin{array}{c}
xyz\\
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 \\-1 \\1 \\
\end{array}
 \right]
 \begin{matrix}
\\yz\\xz\\xy
 \end{matrix}
}S^3
\xrightarrow{
\begin{array}{rrr}
yz&xz&xy\\
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0&1&1\\
1&0&-1\\
-1&-1&0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
}S^3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I want to align the row yz xz xy with the top row of the 3 by 3 matrix given in the code

Comment: There is at least one `\end{array}` missing. At least your code does not compile. Please try to give us compilable code and to give more information on what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: But the problem still persists.

Comment: But know I can see what you have been talking about. You could minimize your code a lot to the actual problem. The solution to your problem is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59517 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223501 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46722 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  0 ―――→ S
  \xrightarrow{
  xyz
  \begin{bsmallmatrix*}[r]
  1 \\-1 \\1
  \end{bsmallmatrix*}
  \begin{smallmatrix}
  yz\\xz\\xy
  \end{smallmatrix}%
  }S³
  \xrightarrow{
  \begin{matrix}
  \begin{smallmatrix*}
    & yz & & zx & & xy \end{smallmatrix*} \\
  \begin{bsmallmatrix*}[r]
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&-1\\
  -1&-1&0\\
  \end{bsmallmatrix*}
  \end{matrix}
  }S³
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]