# Put text above columns and to the right of rows for a bmatrix

Tags: matrices

How would I achieve this matrix in latex:

I am having trouble putting the S,R,C on the top and right respectively.

[image]

Comment: You can use this: [How to create a matrix with rows and columns labeled (at the right side)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46722/5764) (possible duplicate) and just change the delimiters from `(`...`)` to `[`...`]`.

Comment: There is also this: [Label rows of a matrix by characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59517/5764)