# How can I draw this kind of matrix?

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, bordermatrix, blkarray

[image]

How can I draw this kind of matrix?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46722/14757

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- You should show us, what you try so far, so far this is "do-it-for-me" question.
- As you novice here, let me show one possibilities how to write your matrix. It can serve as starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceArray}{*{3}{w{c}{1.2em}}|*{3}{w{c}{1.2em}}}[first-row,first-col,margin]
        & C_1   &\Cdots & C_m   &       &       &       \\
L_1     & \Block{3-3}<\huge>{A} &       &       &         
                                \Block{3-3}<\huge>{B}   &&  \\
\Vdots  &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
L_m     &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \hline
        & \Block{3-3}<\huge>{C} &       &       &
                                \Block{3-3}<\huge>{D}   &&  \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

After (at least) two compilation, you will get:

[image]

I suggest you to read `nicematrix` documentation. It can be find on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en) site.