# Labeling all sides of the matrix with kbordermatrix

Tags: bordermatrix

I have a matrix with labels on the left and top. Now I want to have a label on all sides of the matrix. How can I change my code?

```
\documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
\[
  \tilde{\textbf{m}} = \kbordermatrix{
    \mbox{} & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
    % & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
    r_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    r_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    r_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    r_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    r_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you change to `blkarray`? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45485/1952

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) to construct the components of a multi-indexed array:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kbordermatrix,blkarray}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
\[
  \tilde{\textbf{m}} = \kbordermatrix{
    \mbox{} & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
    r_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    r_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    r_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    r_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    r_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
  }
\]

\newcommand{\idxsize}{\scriptstyle}
\[
  \tilde{\textbf{m}} =
  \begin{blockarray}{>{\scriptstyle}c
      >{\hspace{\arraycolsep}\idxsize}c*{4}{>{\idxsize}c}<{\hspace{\arraycolsep}}>{\idxsize}c}
    & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & \\
    \begin{block}{>{\idxsize}c(>{\hspace{\arraycolsep}}ccccc<{\hspace{\arraycolsep}})>{\idxsize}c}
      r_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & r_5 \\
      r_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & r_4 \\
      r_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & r_3 \\
      r_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & r_2 \\
      r_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & r_1 \\
    \end{block}
    \\[-1.2\normalbaselineskip] & c_5 & c_4 & c_3 & c_2 & c_1 &
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\tilde{\textbf{m}} =
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-col=6,first-row,last-row=6]
    & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
r_1 & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & r_5 \\
r_2 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   & r_4 \\
r_3 & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 1   & r_3 \\
r_4 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 1   & r_2 \\
r_5 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & r_1 \\
    & c_5 & c_4 & c_3 & c_2 & c_1 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]