# How to create a Matrix with Label on its top?

Tags: matrices, blkarray

I've been trying to create a matrix (displayed in the image below), and I haven't been able to figure out so far.
[image]

I've tried the following code (as an example), but its not quite the same as you can see in the image. Can someone please guide me about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
a & b & c & d & e \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1   \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1   \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us what, specifically, you're trying to change. E.g., would you like square brackets instead of round parentheses? Colums or rows of `\dots`? The math font?

Comment: @Mico I'd like to reproduce the exact matrix as shown in figure. So far, I've been unable to create square brackets, T_i and dots. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write elements above and right outside the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45475/write-elements-above-and-right-outside-the-matrix)

Comment: Another likely duplicate: [`\bordermatrix` with brackets `[ ]` instead of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[T_i = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
W_1 & W_2 & W_3 & \cdots & W_m \\ 
e_{11} & e_{22} & e_{31} & \cdots & e_{m1} \\
e_{12} & e_{22} & e_{32} & \cdots & e_{m2} \\
e_{13} & e_{23} & e_{33} & \cdots & e_{m3} \\
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
e_{1K} & e_{2K} & e_{3K} & \cdots & e_{mK} \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 8):

There is `\bordermatrix` macro in plain TeX:

```
$$
  \delcode`(=\delcode`[  \delcode`)=\delcode`]
  T_i =
  \bordermatrix{ & W_1    & W_2    & W_3    & \cdots & W_m    \cr
                 & e_{11} & e_{21} & e_{31} & \cdots & e_{m1} \cr 
                 & e_{12} & e_{22} & e_{32} & \cdots & e_{m2} \cr 
                 & e_{13} & e_{23} & e_{33} & \cdots & e_{m3} \cr 
                 & \vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \cr
                 & e_{13} & e_{23} & e_{33} & \cdots & e_{m3} \cr }
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost done, you only need to change tip of brackets in `block` and replace matrix elements, where you like to have dots with `\cdots` for horizontal dots and `\vdots` for vertical:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\[T_i =
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
W_1 & W_2 & W_3 & \cdots & W_m \\
\begin{block}{[ccccc]}  % <--- observe [ and ] 
e_{11} & e_{22} & e_{31} & \cdots & e_{m1} \\
e_{12} & e_{22} & e_{32} & \cdots & e_{m2} \\
e_{13} & e_{23} & e_{33} & \cdots & e_{m3} \\
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ % <--- observe dots
e_{1K} & e_{2K} & e_{3K} & \cdots & e_{mK} \\ % <--- observe dots
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Code is simple and for final result need only one compilations.

[image]