# How can I add some enhancement to the matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
P=
\begin{bmatrix} 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This produces nice looking matrix. I need two enhancements:
- A box around some elements in matrix with caption
- Labels above the matrix and on the left side (in my example 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7).

My idea is to show and name 'submatrices' in my matrix. If there is better looking way to show what I want, you can change my design.

Pictute showing what I want to acomplish:
[image]

Edit:
There is a problem with `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}`.
Vertical space in matrix is too big when I use it with code from accepted solution.

Comment: Duplicate: Box around sub matrix is covered in: [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix), and labels is covered in [Where is the \matrix command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command).

Comment: Thanks. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix does not cover labelling highlighted area. How can I do that? Yur answer from this question that uses `\tikzmark` is great! What if I want two or more boxes inside matrix?

Comment: Please, don't close yet! Thanks to @Peter Grill, I know how to make labels on the sides of a matrix and how to make highlights inside a matrix, but I still don't know how to label those highlights.

Comment: I have voted to close it since it seems that you have moved to a new question and fixed the issues with this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below I have used `bmatrix` as per your MWE, and `\brodermatrix` from [Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command), along my earlier  solution from [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) to yield the desired results.

Since you are using `\setstretch{1.5}` in your preamble, and this results in too much spacing in the matrices you can adjust that locally within the matrix, as shown below. Since this adjustment is done within a group, there should be no effect on this setting for the rest of your code.

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs: the first to compute the positions of the box, and the second to draw it in the correct spot.
- Since this is using `tikz`, you automatically get all the flexibility inherent in `tikz`, such as line styles, line thickness, line color, fill, etc, a few of which are illustrated in the output. These can be passed to the first parameter to the `\DrawBox` macro to customize each instance or provided as default options to maintain consistency.

### References:

- For matrix options refer to [Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command).
- Other options are available for [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix).
- For the code to extract coordinates, refer to [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz/33706#33706)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[4][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
        \coordinate (TopLeft)     at ($(#2)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$);
        \coordinate (BottomRight) at ($(#3)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);
        %
        \path (TopLeft); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\IgnoreCoord};
        \path (BottomRight); \pgfgetlastxy{\IgnoreCoord}{\YCoord};
        \coordinate (LabelPoint) at ($(\XCoord,\YCoord)!0.5!(BottomRight)$);
        %
        \draw [red,#1] (TopLeft) rectangle (BottomRight);
        \node [below, #1, fill=none, fill opacity=1] at (LabelPoint) {#4};
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\setstretch{1.25}
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmark{left1}0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6                  & 0.0                 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7                  & 0.7                 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3\tikzmark{right1} & 0.0                 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0 \\[12pt]
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0                  & \tikzmark{left2}0.2 & 0.8                  & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0                  &                 0.3 & 0.7\tikzmark{right2} & 0.0 & 0.0 \\[12pt]
                0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1                  &                 0.0 & 0.0                  & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
                0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1                  &                 0.0 & 0.3                  & 0.1 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\DrawBox[thick, red ]{left1}{right1}{\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize$s^1$}}
\DrawBox[thick, blue, dashed]{left2}{right2}{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize$s^2$}}
%-------------
\[\setstretch{1.2}
 \bordermatrix{\text{corner} & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7\cr
    1&\tikzmark{left1} 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6                  &                 0.0 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0\cr
    2&                 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7                  &                 0.7 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0\cr
    4&                 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3\tikzmark{right1} &                 0.0 & 0.0                  & 0.0 & 0.0\cr\cr
    3&                 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0                  & \tikzmark{left2}0.2 & 9.8                  & 0.0 & 0.0\cr
    6&                 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0                  &                 0.3 & 0.7\tikzmark{right2} & 0.0 & 0.0\cr\cr
    5&                 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1                  &                 0.0 & 0.3                  & 0.2 & 0.3\cr
    7&                 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1                  &                 0.0 & 0.3                  & 0.1 & 0.5
}
\]
\DrawBox[thick, red, dotted ]{left1}{right1}{\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize$s^1$}}
\DrawBox[thick, blue,fill=yellow!10, fill opacity=0.3]{left2}{right2}{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize$s^2$}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more thing. I use `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}`. This makes vertical space too big. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Ichibann: This is an easy fix. Have updated the solution to reflect this and also included your MWE.