# How can I create a matrix normal form?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Is it possible to create a matrix like the following draft with LaTeX?

[image]

I have found this [Tikzample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/highlighting-matrix/), but I don't know how to get the dots on the diagonal.

edit: This is how far I got:
[image]

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  & 1 &    &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   & -1 &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  & - 1  &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      & cos \omega_1 & -sin \omega_1  & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      & sin \omega_1 &  cos \omega_1  & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & &              \\
  &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & & cos \omega_2 \\
  &  &   &    &  &      &              &                & & sin \omega_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

The lime part is what I would like to have, but wasn't able to do with LaTeX.

Comment: Can you provide your code without the dots?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47765/how-can-i-add-some-enhancement-to-the-matrix which is duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix

Comment: If you write `\sin` and `\cos` -- note the backslash characters -- you'll get *upright roman* lettering for the sine and cosine functions, rather than the differently-spaced *math italics* that result if you type `sin` and `cos` without the backslash characters.

Comment: @Ichibann: I don't think the new question is a duplicate -- the older question you reference doesn't have the blank spaces off the (block) diagonal of the matrix that are required in the new question.

Comment: @Mico, but blank spaces are the easiest part assuming you already have those borders.

Comment: For reference, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: @Ichibann -- I don't think we should make too many assumptions about what's easy for other LaTeX users and what's not...

Comment: @Mico, you right. I meant that OP already managed to make blank spaces.

Comment: @Ichibann : I didn't know \ddots. This was the part where I had no clue how to solve it. Additionally, I think the boxes are also not that easy to create (although I had an example).

Comment: @Mico : Thanks for your answer :-) It was really helpful => Upvote + Accept, although I think the one of Altermundus looks much nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the vertical and horizontal lines around the matrix blocks, the following solution (which also doesn't require TikZ) may be of interest. (I've updated the example to reflect the update in your question, which appears to require an extra `\ddots` row/column.)

Note that I use the `array` environment rather than the `matrix` (or `pmatrix`) environment as it's necessary to right-align the contents of some columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
% short-hand commands for multicolumn entries with vertical bar
% on left and right hand sides, respectively
\newcommand{\mcl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|r}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left( \,\begin{array}{rcr rcr rr c rr}
\cline{1-3}
 \mcl{1} &        & \mcr{}  \\
 \mcl{}  & \ddots & \mcr{}  \\
 \mcl{}  &        & \mcr{1} \\
\cline{1-6}
 & & & \mcl{-1} &        & \mcr{}  \\
 & & & \mcl{}   & \ddots & \mcr{}  \\
 & & & \mcl{}   &        & \mcr{-1}\\
\cline{4-8}
 & & & & & & \mcl{\cos \omega} & \mcr{-\sin \omega}\\
 & & & & & & \mcl{\sin \omega} & \mcr{ \cos \omega}\\
\cline{7-8} 
 & & & & & & & & \ddots\\
\cline{10-11}
 & & & & & & & & & \mcl{\cos \omega} & \mcr{-\sin \omega}\\
 & & & & & & & & & \mcl{\sin \omega} & \mcr{ \cos \omega}\\
\cline{10-11}
\end{array}\,\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: Using the `\boxed` macro, the code that sets up this matrix can be simplified considerably:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left( \,
\begin{array}{r@{}r@{}r r r}  % @{} is used twice to suppress intercolumn whitespace
  \boxed{ \begin{array}{rrr}              % First block
    1 \\
    & \ddots\\
    & & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \\
  & \boxed{ \begin{array}{rrr}            % Second block
      -1 \\
      & \ddots\\
      & & -1\\
   \end{array} } \\
  & & \boxed{ \begin{array}{rr}           % Third block
        \cos \omega & -\sin \omega\\
        \sin \omega &  \cos \omega\\
      \end{array} } \\
  & & & \ddots\\                          % Fourth "block" -- not boxed
  & & & & \boxed{ \begin{array}{rr}       % Fifth block
            \cos \omega & -\sin \omega\\
            \sin \omega &  \cos \omega\\
          \end{array} } \\
\end{array}\,\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `amsmath` package you can do it without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pmatrix}1&&&&&&&&&\\
        &\ddots&&&&&&&&\\
        &&1&&&&&&&\\
        &&&-1&&&&&&\\
        &&&&\ddots&&&&&\\
        &&&&&-1&&&&\\
        &&&&&&\cos w&-\sin w&&\\
        &&&&&&\sin w&\cos w&&\\
        &&&&&&&&\cos w&-\sin w\\
        &&&&&&&&\sin w&\cos w\\\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

or with those boxes, if you need them:

```
    \[\begin{pmatrix}
            \boxed{\begin{matrix}
                1&&\\
                &\ddots&\\
                &&1
            \end{matrix}}&&&\\
            &\boxed{\begin{matrix}
                -1&&\\
                &\ddots&\\
                &&-1
            \end{matrix}}&&\\
            &&\boxed{\begin{matrix}
                \cos w&-\sin w\\
                \sin w&\cos w
            \end{matrix}}&\\
            &&&\boxed{\begin{matrix}
                \cos w&-\sin w\\
                \sin w&\cos w
            \end{matrix}}
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the excellent code from Stefan : (personally I prefer  tikz's code )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw,fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}​  
\[
  M = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    6 & \ddots & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    11 & 12 & \ddots\tikzmark{right}{} & 14 & 15 \\
    16 & 17 & 18 & \ddots & 20 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right)
  \Highlight[first]
\]

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Something more complex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,fill=#1!15,draw,fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=1pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}

\newcommand{\Highlight}[3]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight=#3,fit=(#1.north west) (#2.south east)]  {};}
}
\begin{document}​  

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
\tikzmark{1}{c}  &  -a              &  0    & \dots  & \dots  & \dots                &  0 \\
              -b & \tikzmark{2}{c}  & -a    & \ddots &        &                      & \vdots \\
               0 &  -b              & \tikzmark{3}{c}    & \ddots & \ddots  &        & \vdots \\
          \vdots & \ddots           & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots              & \vdots \\
          \vdots &                  & \ddots & \ddots &   c    &  -a                 &  0 \\
          \vdots &                  &        & \ddots &  -b    &    \tikzmark{4}{c}  & -a \\
               0 & \dots            & \dots  & \dots  &   0    &  -b                 &  c
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} 
  \Highlight{1}{2}{blue} 
  \Highlight{3}{4}{red}  

\end{document}​
```

[image]