# \bordermatrix with brackets [ ] instead of parentheses ( )

Tags: brackets, bordermatrix

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$
M = \bordermatrix{~ & x & y \cr
              A & 1 & 0 \cr
              B & 0 & 1 \cr}
$
\end{document}
```

But this code makes a matrix with `()` and i would like it to be with `[]`
How do i do this?

Comment: There is also a [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) (look at the last item for documentation) environment available for such purposes.

Comment: See [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An almost direct modification of `\bordermatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\bbordermatrix#1{\begingroup \m@th
  \@tempdima 4.75\p@
  \setbox\z@\vbox{%
    \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\kern2\p@\global\let\cr\endline}}%
    \ialign{$##$\hfil\kern2\p@\kern\@tempdima&\thinspace\hfil$##$\hfil
      &&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \omit\strut\hfil\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}%
      #1\crcr\omit\strut\cr}}%
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\unhbox\@ne\unskip\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\kern\wd\@ne\kern-\@tempdima\left[\kern-\wd\@ne
    \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\box\@ne\kern2\p@}%
    \vcenter{\kern-\ht\@ne\unvbox\z@\kern-\baselineskip}\,\right]$}%
  \null\;\vbox{\kern\ht\@ne\box\tw@}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$
M = \bbordermatrix{ & x & y \cr
              A & 1 & 0 \cr
              B & 0 & 1 \cr}
$
\end{document}
```

I acted on `\left(` and `\right)`, but also changed the value given to `\@tempdima`, smaller because brackets are slimmer than parentheses.

If you don't want such a messy code, just do

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}
```

that does exactly the same changes.

[image]

A slightly different version where the border entries are set in `\scriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\bbordermatrix#1{\begingroup \m@th
  \global\let\perhaps@scriptstyle\scriptstyle
  \@tempdima 4.75\p@
  \setbox\z@\vbox{%
    \def\cr{%
      \crcr
      \noalign{%
        \kern2\p@
        \global\let\cr\endline
        \global\let\perhaps@scriptstyle\relax
      }%
    }%
    \ialign{$\make@scriptstyle{##}$\hfil\kern2\p@\kern\@tempdima
      &\thinspace\hfil$\perhaps@scriptstyle##$\hfil
      &&\quad\hfil$\perhaps@scriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
      \omit\strut\hfil\crcr
      \noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}%
      #1\crcr\omit\strut\cr}}%
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\unhbox\@ne\unskip\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\kern\wd\@ne\kern-\@tempdima\left[\kern-\wd\@ne
    \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\box\@ne\kern2\p@}%
    \vcenter{\kern-\ht\@ne\unvbox\z@\kern-\baselineskip}\,\right]$}%
  \null\;\vbox{\kern\ht\@ne\box\tw@}\endgroup}
\def\make@scriptstyle#1{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$
M = \bbordermatrix{
   & x & y \cr
 A & 1 & 0 \cr
 B & 0 & 1 \cr
}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to also patch the border text to be `\scriptstyle`?  I.e. to replace `$##$` with `$\scriptstyle ##$` or to insert a `\scriptsize` after `\ialign`, e.g. `\ialign{\scriptsize $##$ ...`?  I couldn't get it working with neither `etoolbox` nor `xpatch`.

Comment: @Rasmus Yes, it's possible. Added the hack, but not with `xpatch`, sorry.

Answer (score 20):

Following Herbert Voss' excellent [`mathmode`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) document, you can redefine the `bordermatrix` command to take an optional argument that determines the delimeters

[image]

Note that Herbert also details that the `amsmath` package *offers the same or better macros/environments*

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@borderstar
\def\bordermatrix{\@ifnextchar*{%
\@borderstartrue\@bordermatrix@i}{\@borderstarfalse\@bordermatrix@i*}%
}
\def\@bordermatrix@i*{\@ifnextchar[{\@bordermatrix@ii}{\@bordermatrix@ii[()]}}
\def\@bordermatrix@ii[#1]#2{%
\begingroup
\m@th\@tempdima8.75\p@\setbox\z@\vbox{%
\def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\kern 2\p@\global\let\cr\endline }}%
\ialign {$##$\hfil\kern 2\p@\kern\@tempdima & \thinspace %
\hfil $##$\hfil && \quad\hfil $##$\hfil\crcr\omit\strut %
\hfil\crcr\noalign{\kern -\baselineskip}#2\crcr\omit %
\strut\cr}}%
\setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
\setbox\tw@\hbox{\unhbox\@ne\unskip\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
\setbox\tw@\hbox{%
$\kern\wd\@ne\kern -\@tempdima\left\@firstoftwo#1%
\if@borderstar\kern2pt\else\kern -\wd\@ne\fi%
\global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\box\@ne\if@borderstar\else\kern 2\p@\fi}%
\vcenter{\if@borderstar\else\kern -\ht\@ne\fi%
\unvbox\z@\kern-\if@borderstar2\fi\baselineskip}%
\if@borderstar\kern-2\@tempdima\kern2\p@\else\,\fi\right\@secondoftwo#1 $%
}\null \;\vbox{\kern\ht\@ne\box\tw@}%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
$
M = \bordermatrix[{[]}]{%
            & x & y \cr
          A & 1 & 0 \cr
          B & 0 & 1 }
$

$
M = \bordermatrix[\{\}]{%
            & x & y \cr
          A & 1 & 0 \cr
          B & 0 & 1 }
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Is this it? http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

Comment: @JoelSjögren indeed - thanks, I have updated it :) or else `texdoc mathmode` will also work

Comment: @cmhughes Mathmode has attained **obsolete** status on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=en)

Answer (score 11):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to compose tabulars and mathematical tools. With that package, there is no problem to compose exterior rows and columns for a matrix with square brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$
M = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& x & y \\
A & 1 & 0 \\
B & 0 & 1 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]