# bordermatrix with more space between rows when there are fractional elements

Tags: bordermatrix

I am using a modified version of `\bordermatrix` as defined here:
[\bordermatrix with brackets [ ] instead of parentheses ( )](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/bordermatrix-with-brackets-instead-of-parentheses)

My matrices have fractional elements and I would like to add additional space between rows so the fractions don't touch. With usual matrices this can be done by putting `[0.3em]` at the end of each line, but that doesn't work with bordermatrix since it uses `\cr` instead of `\\` for line breaks, and `\cr` seems not to take arguments.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}

\[\mathbf{P}=\bbordermatrix{& 0 & 1 & 2\cr
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\cr
1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\cr
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0}
\]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) instead (the package is not on CTAN, but can be downloaded following the provided link); in this way, you automatically get square brackets instead of parentheses as delimiters, and you can use the standard `\\[<length>]` syntax; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}

\begin{document}


\[
\mathbf{P}=\bbordermatrix{
& 0 & 1 & 2\cr
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\cr
1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\cr
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0}\qquad
\mathbf{P}=\kbordermatrix{
& 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\[1ex]
1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\[1ex]
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\[0.3ex]} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a couple of patches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}

% Add some space between rows
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\openup1\jot}{}{}
% Add the same amount at the end
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}
  {\vcenter{\kern-\ht\@ne\unvbox\z@\kern-\baselineskip}}
  {\vcenter{\kern-\ht\@ne\unvbox\z@\kern-\baselineskip\kern2pt}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{P}=\bbordermatrix{& 0 & 1 & 2\cr
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\cr
1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\cr
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]