# Bordermatrix without brackets

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

I am hanging on this one since yesterday and was not able to find an example nor anything in the documentation --- maybe I am blind?

What i want is a matrix with border annotations BUT without the brackets (neither round nor squared nor curled, each of which have been discussed here). I also want to make the bordertext (A-E) bold and italic on the X and the Y axis...

I have some code to construct the matrix as I have it right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\VR{\kern-\arraycolsep\strut\vrule &\kern-\arraycolsep}
\def\vr{\kern-\arraycolsep & \kern-\arraycolsep}

\begin{document}

\LARGE
$\bordermatrix{
   & A & B & C & D & E \cr
 A & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \cr
 B & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
 C & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \cr
 D & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
 E & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 }$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you need to use a `tabular`, not a matrix.

Comment: If you need to patch the bordermatrix, just see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054

Comment: I'm not sure: you want to have no brackets and then change the font properties of the external letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\bordermatrix`, that's all!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} *{5}{c}}
  &
  \itshape A &
  \itshape B &
  \itshape C &
  \itshape D &
  \itshape E
\\[1ex]
\bfseries A & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\bfseries B & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\bfseries C & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\bfseries D & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\bfseries E & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the column and row headers to be bold italic, just tell TeX to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\bolditalic}{\bfseries\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} *{5}{c}}
  &
  \bolditalic A &
  \bolditalic B &
  \bolditalic C &
  \bolditalic D &
  \bolditalic E
\\[1ex]
\bolditalic A & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\bolditalic B & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\bolditalic C & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\bolditalic D & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\bolditalic E & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For first column you can use `>{\bfseries}c`` or `>{\bfseries\itshape}c`` and omit `\bfseries` or `bolditalic` in each cells of this column.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, that's a possibility, but requires loading the `array` package. Not a big deal, of course.