# confusion matrix with [ ] delimeters

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

I would like to make a confusion matrix that looks like the one on the picture. How can I achive this? Thanks 
[image]

Comment: similar: [`\bordermatrix` with brackets `[ ]` instead of parentheses `( )`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite hard coded, but you may start with this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{blockarray}{c@{}ccc}
&&\BAmulticolumn{2}{c}{\text{observed}}\\[-2\jot]
&& 0 & 1 \\
\begin{block}{c@{\hspace{.6em}}c[cc]}
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{predicted}} & 0 & a=1 & b=2\\
& 1 & c=3 & d=4 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @OlgaLyashevska Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of the eponymous package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
  &   & \Block{1-2}{\text{observed}} \\
  &   & 0   & 1 \\
  \Block{2-1}{\rotate \text{predicted}}
  & 0 & a=1 & b=2 \\[1mm]
  & 1 & c=2 & d=4 
\CodeAfter 
  \SubMatrix[{3-3}{4-4}]
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]