# How to label rows and columns matrix?

Tags: matrices

I'm using LaTeX to do some basic matrix creation in a GeoGebra document as shown below:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
```

And it results in this:
[image]

However, I would like to label each of the rows and columns as this is meant to be a tennis dominance matrix that is to be accompanied by a digraph. I know that using a normal TeX editor would allow me to use a package, however, GeoGebra doesn't allow for such plugins. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Note: I apologise for the way the LaTeX code is awkwardly displayed.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow- thanks for the edit

Comment: Do you want to visually name the rows and columns, or apply names for later reference in the document (as in, automatic reference)?

Comment: I wish to visually label them

Comment: this might help: [\bordermatrix with brackets instead of parentheses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054)