# How to write a matrix of the form that I mentioned in the figure below

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How can we write a matrix of the form I  posted below. Hope you will give an answer.

[image: how to write a matrix in latex of the form mentioned below]

Comment: Have you tried 

     \left[ \begin{tabular}{ccc} 
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
     1 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     \end{tabular} \right]  ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/bordermatrix-with-brackets-instead-of-parentheses/55056#55056

Answer (score 6):

You could use `blkarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\begin{block}{c[ccc]}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]