# How can I type text above a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, alignment

I'm trying to write a matrix like the one in the image, but I don't know how to do it (I tried using the `align` environment, but I had no luck). Any help will be really appreciated. :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You could do that with the  `blkarray` package.

Comment: Also `nicematrix` is promising candidate.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. You can try with kbordermatrix, spalign, nicematrix package for example. But I'm scared of the photo is not that you come from Dante Alighieri's hell? Italy celebrates 700 years since his birth.:-)))))) I'm joking.

Comment: @Sebastiano: A Cat in hell ??? ;o)

Comment: Thank you guys sooo much, I was struggling a lot with this one :( I'll try with those packages, thank youuu <3

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/bordermatrix-with-brackets-instead-of-parentheses for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses only some very basic LaTeX packages, along with `center`, `tabular`, and `bmatrix` environments. I've tried as much as possible to mimic the layout in the screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor,amsmath,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} r @{} l c >{\hspace{7mm}}l @{}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor{cyan}{From:}} & \\
& \textcolor{cyan}{City} 
& \textcolor{cyan}{Subu\rlap{rbs}} % ok, the use of '\rlap' is kludgy...
& \textcolor{cyan}{To:} \\[0.75ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{$M{=}$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\multirow{2}{*}{%
    $\begin{bmatrix} 
           0.95 & 0.03 \\ 
           0.05 & 0.97 
     \end{bmatrix}$}}
& \textcolor{cyan}{City} \\
& & & \textcolor{cyan}{Suburbs} 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

You put all the elements (text and numbers) in a great array and you put the brackets where you want with the command `\SubMatrix` in the `\CodeAfter`.

With the key `baseline`, you put the baseline where you want (for the alignment with `M=`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cyan}{\color{cyan}}

$M = \begin{NiceTabular}{cc>{\cyan}l}[baseline=line-4]
\Block{1-2}{\cyan From:} \\
\cyan City  & \cyan Suburbs & To: \\
$.95$ & $.03$ & City \\
$.05$ & $.97$ & Suburbs \\
\CodeAfter \SubMatrix[{3-1}{4-2}][slim]
\end{NiceTabular}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Excellent your package :-)