# Misplaced alignment tab character when building a matrix

Tags: math-mode, errors, matrices

I'm still new to latex. I've been having a problem with building a matrix and I have no idea what I'm doing (or what I'm doing wrong), so be gentle please :)

```
\begin{matrix} 
5 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & P & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}
```

This is the code for building the matrix and I keep getting error:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character & 5 &
...
```

Can anyone shine some light please?

Comment: You need to load the `amsmath` package.  Check out the [`mathmode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) documentation.  Also, posting code fragments like this isn't the best way to get answers.  See [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693).

Comment: For more on matrices, and the variety of mixes out there, see [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `matrix` *macro* is defined as part of the basic LaTeX distribution, but you're probably after the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) implementation of it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
5 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & P & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

The older (TeX) `\matrix` equivalent actually looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\matrix{%
5 & 6 & 7 \cr
4 & P & 0 \cr
3 & 2 & 1
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\matrix` is a macro taking a single argument, and not an environment.

Comment: It started giving me this error "command \implies already defined" and "command \overset already defined"

Comment: This appened after importing the amsmath

Comment: It worked. had to add the package as the first package :) tks

Answer (score 5):

Standard LaTeX does not have a matrix environment. For historical reasons the original version of LaTeX (LaTeX 2.09) contained a more or less full copy of plain TeX commands including a `\matrix` command. Some of these plain TeX commands made little to no sense in LaTeX as they used quite different conventions  (and some of them didn't even work at all with LaTeX such as `\topinsert` or `\beginsection`). Some made sense and they got documented in the LaTeX manual as "LaTeX commands".

So when LaTeX2e (the current version of LaTeX) was designed, we took those that did not work out. However, those that did work (even if not documented and with unusual syntax) have been kept for compatibility reasons, just in case somebody did use them in old documents. E.g.,

```
\maxtrix{5 & 6 & 7 \cr
        4 & P & 0 \cr
        3 & 2 & 1 \cr}
```

should work in plain TeX (and in fact in LaTeX). But neither `\cr` nor `\matrix` is a documented and official LaTeX command. And as you can see it is a command with one argument not an environment, which is why you get your error message.

In LaTeX it is best to load the `amsmath` package that provides all kind of good math support including a `matrix` environment that supports the syntax you used.