# Multicolumn vector

Tags: math-mode, vector

How can I create a vector like this one?

[image: two-column vector]

It is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/typesetting-column-vector) question, but with additional columns.

Comment: The precise output depends on the desired packages ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty approach with `pmatrix` environment

The individual columns are separated by a `&` character, the next linebreak is achieved with `\\`

If one replaces `pmatrix` with `bmatrix`, the `[ ]` version is obtained

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 A =  \begin{pmatrix}
   3 & 5 \\
   5 & 2 \\
   2 & 1 \\
   1 & 4 \\
   7 & 9 
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not ``\\`` instead of `\cr`?

Comment: @Manuel: I always used `\cr` ;-) If it works with `\\ ` too, the better ;-)

Comment: clean enough for me ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you tell me where in the LaTeX manual or the doc for `amsmath` there's a description of `\cr`? Possibly I didn't read them carefully enough. Out of joke: ***DON'T*** use `\cr` in LaTeX documents.

Comment: @egreg: It's perhaps some old style but I am sure that I have seen it (not in a  manual, though) with the `\cr` way ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's not “old style”: it's wrong. You may have seen `\matrix{1 & 2\cr 3 & 4\cr}` using the LaTeX command inherited from Plain, that's supplanted by `matrix` of `amsmath` (and the other environments adding parentheses). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57658/misplaced-alignment-tab-character-when-building-a-matrix

Comment: Why an `align*` environment?