# Equation number for each row of a matrix equation

Tags: equations, labels, subequations

Is it possible to give an equation number to each row of a matrix equation?

[image]

How could I have equation labels in the vein of subequation numbers, one for each row of the matrix equation? Here, I'd like equation numbers such as, e.g., (3.1a), (3.1b), (3.1c) (I don't mean row/column labels as in a bordered matrix).

Thanks!

Comment: Use an image we don't use mathjax on this site as it would confuse the issue as people need to show the tex rendering amd mathjax does not use tex

Comment: Related, but not automatic numbering: [Label rows of a matrix by characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters)

Comment: I can't understand what the line number would refer to.

Comment: @egreg each line number would refer to a block equation of the system.

Comment: It's really unclear, in my opinion.

Comment: But matrix multiplication is rows by `columns`! Labeling rows doesn't make sense if there is a matrix product in your equation.

Comment: There are three block row equations in the matrix equation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmm! not really supported LaTeX syntax but

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox\labelbox

\begin{document}

\savebox\labelbox{$\begin{matrix}
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{aa}\\
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{bb}\\
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{cc}
\end{matrix}$}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    H            & J^T       & -Z^{\frac12} \\
    J            & -\delta I &              \\
    -Z^{\frac12} &           & -X
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    r \\ s \\ t
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \lambda
  \begin{bmatrix}
    H &   &  \\
      & U &  \\
      &   & W
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    r \\ s \\ t
  \end{bmatrix}
\eqno
\usebox{\labelbox}
\]

[\ref{aa}]
[\ref{bb}]
[\ref{cc}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting (and potentially useful) technique.  Is there anything that can go wrong with it?

Comment: I didn't think of that. I like it! Why do you say it's not supported?It's not inelegant.

Comment: `\eqno` is a TeX primitive and wouldn't generally work in conjunction with amsmath constructs, but you get away with it here. Probably you could (and should) use `\tag` in other contexts.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes something can go wrong with anything:-) `\eqno` shouldn't be used in latex (and wouldn't work in most ams math constructs) but it works here and I was getting tired:-)

Comment: But you know me.  I'm not contemplating using in with ams math constructs, but rather with TABstacks `;^)`

Comment: I guess now I'm not sure how to assign labels to the equation numbers so as to refer to them individually?!

Comment: @Dominique put `\label{foo}` immediately after `\refstepcounter{equation}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But that gives me `Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:gen-eig' will be lost.`

Comment: @Dominique sorry: try now I updated the answer with a workaround where you use the labeled numbers in a box before the equation.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - David Carlisle (and some other frequent contributors this site too...) prefer *not* to capitalize most words. Is there a need to teach David a different set of spelling rules by editing their postings?

Comment: @Mico Do you really thing I'm trying to teach David something? I probably can't teach him anything. But don't worry; I won't edit posts in the future.

Comment: @Mico I don't think you can ping him from here unless he's in the comment thread:-) But yes not capitalising latex is more or less intentional (although I'm not barabara:-)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg oh you are there:-) Did mico's ping work or were you passing by?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle His ping worked just fine. `:)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Many thanks! It even works with subequations. Much easier to read block equations in my opinion.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Odd  `@ s` now offers your name now you are in the thread but if you were "just" here as editor it doesn't offer your name and I though @ ping didn't work in that case. As for editing my typing is pretty appalling so in general I don't mind people editing my text (although I tend not to use the logo capitalisation:-)

Comment: @Mico ...and I mean _ever_ change anything in other peoples' posts again when I get accused of stuff like that.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - I'm concerned now that my initial comment got over- and mis-interpreted: It's just that some people have their own particular capitalization habits, and "correcting" the results will probably not change those habits, right? I'm in the habit of editing postings that contain clear typos (and I'm glad when other correct my typos!), but I don't tackle capitalization matters. Let's delete these comments now -- you go first!

Answer (score 0):

Below there is a possible quick and dirty alternative if one needs AMS-`\tag`s. 
The drawback is that it requires some manual height adjustment in the first `matrix`. This solution would not exist without the solution of David. Thanks, David! I needed this too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\par\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{0.9\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
  \begin{matrix}
    1\cdot x_1&+&2\cdot x_2&+&3\cdot x_3&=&4\\[3pt]
    5\cdot x_1&+&6\cdot x_2&+&7\cdot x_3&=&8\\[3pt]
    9\cdot x_1&+&10\cdot x_2&+&11\cdot x_4&=&12
  \end{matrix}
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{align}\refstepcounter{equation}
    \tag{\theequation a}\label{eq:1a}\\[0pt]
    \tag{\theequation b}\label{eq:1b}\\[0pt]
    \tag{\theequation c}\label{eq:1c}    
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are the matrices?

Answer (score 0):

By accident I discovered a simple and straight-forward way. If one has some large column in the actual matrix one should set a corresponding phantom in the numeration matrix. One could also add a `\displaystyle` in the equation number matrix if that is really needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\refstepcounter{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    H            & J^T       & -Z^{\frac12} \\
    J            & -\delta I &              \\
    -Z^{\frac12} &           & -X
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    r \\ s \\ t
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \lambda
  \begin{bmatrix}
    H &   &  \\
    & U &  \\
    &   & W
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    r \\ s \\ t
  \end{bmatrix}
  \tag*{$\begin{matrix}
      \text{(\theequation a)}\\
      \text{(\theequation b)}\\
      \text{(\theequation c)}
    \end{matrix}$}
  \ltxlabel{eq:matrix}
\end{align}
The first row (\ref{eq:matrix}a) is the most important row of the matrix.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to manually avoid the need to manipulate the counter.  I create two `\vbox`es.  The first is an array of blank subequations, and the second is the desired matrix in a simple `\[...\]` construct.  Then I stack the two `\vbox`es atop each other.  Voila!

I've even set it up so that adjusting the vertical baselineskip of the matrix (since I used TABstacks) is automatically reflected in the vertical separation of the equation numbering (through the use of the `\aligngap` macro).

One could, if desired, replace my TABstacks with `{bmatrix}`es and it would still work, though the definition of `\aligngap` would in that case, need some tweaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine,lipsum}
\newsavebox\boxA
\def\aligngap{\dimexpr\Lstackgap-15pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\setstackgap{L}{14pt}% SELECTABLE MATRIX ROW BASELINESKIP
\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{subequations}%
  \begin{align}\label{eq:A}\\[\aligngap]\label{eq:B} \\[\aligngap]\label{eq:C}\end{align}%
  \end{subequations}}
\savebox\boxA{\vbox{\[
  \setstacktabbedgap{5pt}
  \bracketMatrixstack{
    H            & J^T       & -Z^{\frac12} \\
    J            & -\delta I &              \\
    -Z^{\frac12} &           & -X}
  \bracketVectorstack{r \\ s \\ t}
  =
  \lambda
  \bracketMatrixstack{
    H &   &  \\
      & U &  \\
      &   & W}
  \bracketVectorstack{r \\ s \\ t}
\]}}
\noindent\stackengine{3.5pt}{\box0}{\usebox{\boxA}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}

In equations \ref{eq:A}, \ref{eq:B}, and \ref{eq:C},
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]