# Elegant way to typeset labels for matrix coefficients

Tags: amsmath

In *The Econometrics of Financial Markets* by Campbell, Lo and MacKinlay -- a beautifully typeset book -- I have found gorgeous cross correlation matrices of the style below.

[image: Cross correlation tables]

What is an elegant way to typeset these labels for the rows and columns in LaTeX (ideally in conjunction with the `amsmath` matrices)?

Comment: Have you looked into using the [blkarray](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) package?

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59732/14757

Comment: I would like to specifically do this using the amsmath matrices, if this is at all possible.

Comment: What's so special about the matrix-like environments (e.g., `pmatrix`) of the `amsmath` package?

Answer (score 2):

I used tabstacks to set this.  Because all the columns were equal width, I could detmine that width easily using `\BXset`, and overset the labels in boxes of the same size with `\BX`.  If you want more vertical gap in the lines, `\setstackgap{L}{length}` can do that.  The `\setstacktabbedgap` macro sets the intercolumn gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\newlength\BXwidth
\newcommand\BXset[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\BXwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\tabbed@gap\relax}
\makeatother
\newcommand\BX[1]{\makebox[\BXwidth]{$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstacktabbedgap{3ex}
\hat\mathbf{Y}_1 = 
\Centerstack{R_{1t-1}\\R_{2t-1}\\R_{3t-1}\\R_{4t-1}\\R_{5t-1}}
\stackon{
\parenMatrixstack{
0.352 & 0.226 & 0.171 & 0.115 & 0.024\\
0.330 & 0.232 & 0.182 & 0.129 & 0.037\\
0.324 & 0.244 & 0.197 & 0.147 & 0.053\\
0.310 & 0.242 & 0.201 & 0.153 & 0.059\\
0.265 & 0.223 & 0.187 & 0.147 & 0.057
}
}{\BXset{0.352}\BX{R_{1t}}\BX{R_{2t}}\BX{R_{3t}}\BX{R_{4t}}\BX{R_{5t}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]