# Labelling the outside of a large matrix

Tags: equations, matrices

I've been struggling to fit a large matrix on a page, and have finally managed to fit it in, although I had to make the entries very small. Now I want label the rows and columns of the matrix. There is a good answer already on how to do this: [Label rows of a matrix by characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters).

However, I am using a different environment to the ones used in the answers to that topic. Since it took me a long time to get my large matrix to fit on the page, I don't want to have to start again from scratch. Is there some code that will allow me to add labelling around the edge whilst only requiring minor alterations to what I already have?

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: Large matrix]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation* and bmatrix environment
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} % for the large matrices

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{4.9}{5.8}\selectfont % Fontsize may only come in 4pt and 5pt because there is a huge leap from 4.9 to 5
\noindent\hspace{-1.7in}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth+3.4in}
\begin{equation*}\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\begin{pmatrix}
Lk(l_{1,1},l_{1,1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{1,1},l_{1,2}^{\#}) & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots   & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & Lk(l_{1,1},l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) \\
Lk(l_{1,2},l_{1,1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{1,2},l_{1,2}^{\#}) & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & Lk(l_{1,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{1,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) &   Lk(l_{1,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{2,1}^{\#}) & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots  & Lk(l_{2,1},l_{1,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{2,1},l_{2,1}^{\#}) & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & Lk(l_{2,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{2,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{2,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{2,2}^{\#}) & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & Lk(l_{2,2},l_{2,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{2,2},l_{2,2}^{\#}) & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & Lk(l_{\frac{n}{2}-2,\frac{m}{2}-2},l_{\frac{n}{2}-2,\frac{m}{2}-2}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-2}^{\#})  \\
Lk(l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{1,1}^{\#}) & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots    & \cdots  & \cdots & Lk(l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-2},l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) \\
\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}\hspace{-1.7in}
}

\end{document}
```

Apologies in advance for all the horizontal scrolling you will have to do: I'm not sure how to prevent that.

Comment: You mean to label both rows and columns?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: submatrix representation]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation* and bmatrix environment
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} % for the large matrices

\begin{document}

I'm trying to figure out the pattern here. 
You might consider a submatrix representation of the form
\begin{equation*}
\left( \begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
A(1,1) & A(1,2) & \cdots & A(1,m) \\
\hline
A(2,1) & A(2,2) & \cdots & A(2,m) \\
\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\hline
A(n,1) & A(n,2) & \cdots & A(n,m)
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}
where each $\frac{m}{2}-1\times \frac{m}{2}-1$ submatrix is given by 
\begin{equation*}
\def\arraystretchfactor{1.2}
A(i,j) = \begin{pmatrix}
Lk(l_{i,1},l_{j,1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{i,1},l_{j,2}^{\#}) & \cdots & Lk(l_{i,1},l_{j,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) \\
Lk(l_{i,2},l_{j,1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{i,2},l_{j,2}^{\#}) & \cdots & Lk(l_{i,2},l_{j,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
Lk(l_{i,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{j,1}^{\#}) & Lk(l_{i,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{j,2}^{\#}) & \cdots & Lk(l_{i,\frac{m}{2}-1},l_{j,\frac{m}{2}-1}^{\#})
\end{pmatrix}
\quad.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

BTW, it is possible (but difficult) to show row and column indexes on the outside of a matrix, but with a submatrix representation you shouldn't need it.

Comment: At first I wasn't sure if this would work, but looking closely I see it does - and also it fixes the problem of fitting the large matrix on the page. Really nice answer.

Comment: On second thought, it might look better to drop the division lines, or use the arydshln package.