# how to label rows and columns of matrix?

Tags: matrices

i have a matrix as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
& S1 & S2 & S3 & S4 \\
W1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ % inserting body of the table
W2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0    
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

i want to write labels S1,S2,S3,S4 and W1,W2 outside the brackets instead of inside, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See if [Label rows of a matrix by characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59517) answers your question.

Comment: actually this gives me an error `kbordermatrix.sty` missing, anyways i'll download the .sty file and give it a try

Comment: and yes the problem is solved -  thanks for the guide

Comment: There was also the other answer there of course, which uses a package (`blkarray`) that is on CTAN and in TeX Live and MikTeX.