# Printing matrix labels below it

Tags: matrices

So i created a matrix in latex using the code:

```
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{blkarray
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
\[
   \kbordermatrix{
    & a & b & c & d\\
    a & 2173.00 & 354.00 & 0.00 & 1249.00 \\
    b & 0.00 & 3772.00 & 52.00 & 0.00 \\
    c & 474.00 & 469.00 & 2858.00 & 42.00 \\
    d & 1262.00 & 303.00 & 39.00 & 2180.00\\
  } 
\]
```

The above code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters)
The output matrix which I got is this: [image]

My doubt lies in my next task. I want to put a row of labels below my matrix like: [image]

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From the `kbordermatrix` docs: *I also have an experimental version that will put the labels on the right and bottom. If you ask, I will make it
available. I might even try to make a version that lets you specify the layout, but I am content with top and left.*

Comment: @percusse It would be really helpful if you can make it available. I need the labels below the matrix

Comment: percusse is only quoting from the documentation, but is not the author. You have to contact Kim C Border, kcb@caltech.edu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `blockarray` the parentheses have a tendency to be too small, but it's easy to coerce them to be a bit larger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
\begin{block}{c(cccc)}
a & 2173.00 & 354.00 & 0.00 & 1249.00\smash[b]{\vphantom{\Big|}} \\
b & 0.00 & 3772.00 & 52.00 & 0.00 \\
c & 474.00 & 469.00 & 2858.00 & 42.00 \\
d & 1262.00 & 303.00 & 39.00 & 2180.00\smash[t]{\vphantom{\Big|}}\\
\end{block}
& a & b & c & d
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]