# matrix with number in bracket while description out side of it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices, thesis, block

I'm wondering if there is a method to make such matrix:
[image]

I've tried this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters), but the description text cannot be aligned left:
[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated!

BTW, as suggested by CarLaTeX, I've posted my latex code here for the convenience of all the later readers:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{blkarray} %block array
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}x = \begin{blockarray}{cc}
\begin{block}{(c)c}
  \dots & \dots \\
  0 & \text{android.hardware.wifi} \\
  1 & \text{android.hardware.telephony} \\
  \dots & \dots \\
  1 & \text{SEND\_SMS} \\
  0 & \text{DELETE\_PACKAGES} \\
  \dots & \dots \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of putting an image of your code, cut and paste it in your question, using the *edit* button (bottom on the left). In this way we can copy your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and help you much more easily.

Comment: For the downvoter of my incorrect answer: that was clearly a comment posted like an answer by mistake, a simple comment telling me to correct it would have been sufficient. I don't mind about reputation points lost (I've regained them) but I don't think you have acted in the correct way.

Comment: I can suggest a fast link where you can create your matrix, http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables. It is wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Never thought about there is a way to create matrix in a website and it will generate latex code for you :) that's cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `blkarray` it is possible. Just specify `l` for the text column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow, bigdelim}
\begin{document}

\[
\phi(x) \mapsto 
\begin{blockarray}{(c) l l}
    \cdots & \cdots & \rdelim\}{3}*[$S_1$] \\
    0 & \mathtt{android.hardware.wifi} & \\
    1 & \mathtt{android.hardware.telephony} & \\
    \cdots & \cdots &  \rdelim\}{3}*[$S_2$] \\
    0 & \mathtt{SEND\_SMS} & \\
    1 & \mathtt{DELETE\_PACKAGES} & \\
    \cdots & & \cdots \\
\end{blockarray}

\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! I've tride the '&' align symbol, but it's behavior is wired. There might be many hidden tricks in blkarray I've never heard about.