# Matrix numbering before Line and Column

Tags: amsmath, matrices, tikz-matrix

I want some help, with this script :

```
\begin{center}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{center}
```

I get this Matrix :

[image]

But I want a matrix like this :

[image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can do it with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[ \newcounter{rowct}\newcounter{colct}%\setlength\extrarowheight{1cm}
A =
\begin{blockarray}{*{11}{c}}
\begin{block}{r*{10}{>{\refstepcounter{colct}\mathclap{\mathbf\thecolct}}c}}
 & & & & & & & & & & \\%[-1ex]
 \end{block}
 \begin{block}{ >{\refstepcounter{rowct}\mathbf\therowct}r( >{\hspace{0.2em}}*{10}{c} <{\hspace{0.2em}})}
  &0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \rule{0pt}{3.5ex} \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, a simple fix is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
A = 
\begin{matrix}
1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10
\end{matrix}
\stackon[1pt]{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
}{
\begin{matrix}
~1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10
\end{matrix}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you indeed wanted the labels in bold,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackTextstyle{\bfseries}
\setstacktabbedgap{9.2pt}
\begin{document}
\[
A = 
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10}
\stackon[1pt]{$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$%
}{%
\;\;\tabbedCenterstack{1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10}%
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$A = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
  [
    first-row,
    code-for-first-row = \mathbf{\arabic{jCol}},
    first-col,
    code-for-first-col = \mathbf{\arabic{iRow}},
    columns-width=auto,
  ]
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
& 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]