# How to change brackets for this modified matrix?

Tags: matrices, arrays, brackets, blkarray

I found this code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372402/matrix-numbering-before-line-and-column) (stackexchange) and modified it for the matrix I needed to make. But I want to have thoses brackets[ ]. I tried to change blockarray for \left[ and \right]. Can anybody help me please? I needed \usepackage{blkarray} for this.

```
 \[ \newcounter{rowct}\newcounter{colct}%\setlength\extrarowheight{1cm}
    \begin{blockarray}{*{8}{c}}
    \begin{block}{r*{7}{>{\refstepcounter{colct}\mathclap{\mathbf\thecolct}}c}}
     & & & & & & & \\%[-1ex]
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{ >{\refstepcounter{rowct}\mathbf\therowct}r( >{\hspace{0.2em}}*{7}{c} <{\hspace{0.2em}})}
      & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \rule{0pt}{3.5ex} \\
      & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
      & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\[1ex]
     \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
    \]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the pair `( )` in the second block with a pair of `[ ]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[ \newcounter{rowct}\newcounter{colct}%\setlength\extrarowheight{1cm}
\begin{blockarray}{*{8}{c}}
\begin{block}{r*{7}{>{\refstepcounter{colct}\mathclap{\mathbf\thecolct}}c}}
 & & & & & & & \\%[-1ex]
 \end{block}
 \begin{block}{ >{\refstepcounter{rowct}\mathbf\therowct}r[ >{\hspace{0.2em}}*{7}{c} <{\hspace{0.2em}}]}
  & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \rule{0pt}{3.5ex} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\[1ex]
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! This answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}%
  [ 
   first-row,
   code-for-first-row = \mathbf{\arabic{jCol}},
   first-col,
   code-for-first-col = \mathbf{\arabic{iRow}},
  ]
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
& 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
& 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]