# How can I draw this Matrix?

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

How can I make this matrix in LaTeX ?

[image]

My MWE :

```
$
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11} & . & .  & x_{1n} \\
 . & . & . & . \\
 . & . & . & . \\
 x_{m1} & . & .  & x_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
$
```

I get this :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the dots are shifted from one row to another.

Comment: I don't want them to be like in the first picture. But I can solve my problem now : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters