# align elements of matrix with a bmatrix inside

Tags: align, matrices

I have made the following matrix:

```
\newcommand{\mtx}[2]{\begin{#1matrix}#2\end{#1matrix}}
\newcommand{\mtxR}[2]{\begin{#1matrix*}[r]#2\end{#1matrix*}}
\begin{equation*}
    A=\mtx{}{\mtx{}{e_1&e_2&e_3&e_4&e_5&e_6&e_7&e_8}&\\\mtxR{b}{1&&1&&&&&\\-1&1&&1&&&&\\&-1&&&1&1&&\\&&&&-1&-1&&1\\&&&-1&&&1&-1\\&&-1&&&&-1&}&\mtx{}{v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\\v_5\\v_6}}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Is there a way to align the e's in the top row with the numbers in the bmatrix, and the same for the v's in the most right column?

Comment: `blkarray` may be a solution to this:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59519/15036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[
A=\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 \\
\begin{block}{[ccccc]l}
  1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & v_1 \\
    & 1  &   &   & 1 & v_2 \\
    &    & 1 &   & 1 & v_3 \\
    &    &   & 1 & 1 & v_4 \\
    &    &   &   & 1 & v_5 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the `1` and the `-1` entries to line up so that the numerals were exactly under each other, you could try defining the inner `block` with `[rrrrr]l`.  But you might think (for example) that the right hand column was too close to the right bracket.

Or you can "cheat" with `\smash` to set the minus signs in zero-width boxes.  Personally I don't mind the `-1` entries sticking out to the right a bit, as I think it might make them easier to read.

Or you can use `nicematrix` as the other answer shows.

Comment: Unfortunately, any negative element won't be nicely aligned.  That's why the starred form of `matrix` (requiring `mathtools`) was used in the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton true, but I was trying to keep things as simple as possible and just answer the bit about the labels.  I know tastes differ, but personally I don't mind the centred -1 sticking out a bit -- I think it can actually be easier to read. But I would not want to die in a ditch about it.

Comment: The reason I mentioned it is that the OP has negatives scattered heavily throughout, and went to great effort to have the digits aligned.  My inclination is to observe and honor that.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `nicematrix`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{*{8}{R}}[
  first-row,
  last-col,
]
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 & e_7 & e_8 & \\
  1 &     &   1 &     &     &     &     &     & v_1 \\
 -1 &   1 &     &   1 &     &     &     &     & v_2 \\
    &  -1 &     &     &   1 &   1 &     &     & v_3 \\
    &     &     &     &  -1 &  -1 &     &   1 & v_4 \\
    &     &     &  -1 &     &     &   1 &  -1 & v_5 \\
    &     &  -1 &     &     &     &  -1 &     & v_6 \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make the column labels centred, while keeping the elements right aligned?

Comment: @Thruston `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways: with `blkarray` and with `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, blkarray}
\usepackage{bigdelim} 

\begin{document}

\[ A = \begin{blockarray}{*{8}{r}l}
  e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 & e-7 & e_8 & \\
\begin{block}{[*{8}{r}]@{\quad}l}
  1 & & 1 & & & & & & v_1 \\
-1 & 1 & &1 & & & & & v_2 \\
 & -1 & & & 1 & 1 & & & v_3 \\
 & & & & -1 & -1 & & 1 & v_4 \\
  & & & -1 & & & 1 & -1 & v_5 \\
 & & -1 & & & & -1 & &v_6 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\[ A = \begin{array}{r@{\,}*{8}{r}@{\,}l@{}l}
  & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 & e-7 & e_8 & \\
\ldelim[{6}{*} & 1 & & 1 & & & & & & \rdelim]{6}{*} & v_1 \\
& -1 & 1 & &1 & & & & & & v_2 \\
& & -1 & & & 1 & 1 & & & & v_3 \\
& & & & & -1 & -1 & & 1 & & v_4 \\
& & & & -1 & & & 1 & -1 & & v_5 \\
& & & -1 & & & & -1 & & & v_6
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really mean `$e-7$` or `$e_7$`?  (I think the latter.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nicematrix` and its nice keys like `code-for-first-row` and `code-for-last-col`. That way you do not have to type `e_1`, `e_2` etc. nor `v_1`, `v_2` and so on. This also allows you to center the entries of a column or row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[\pgfmathsetmacro{\myw}{width("$-1$")}
\begin{bNiceArray}{*{8}{R}}[
  first-row,
  last-col,
  code-for-first-row = \makebox[\myw pt][c]{$e_{\arabic{jCol}}$},
  code-for-last-col = v_{\arabic{iRow}}
]
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
  1 &     &   1 &     &     &     &     &     &  \\
 -1 &   1 &     &   1 &     &     &     &     &  \\
    &  -1 &     &     &   1 &   1 &     &     &  \\
    &     &     &     &  -1 &  -1 &     &   1 &  \\
    &     &     &  -1 &     &     &   1 &  -1 &  \\
    &     &  -1 &     &     &     &  -1 &     &  \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]