# Using \usepackage in Google Colab

Tags: packages, matrices

I am trying to use Google Colab with LaTex to make a matrix with column and row labels. Outside of Colab, the code that I would need is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
a & b & c & d & e \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & f \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & g \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & h \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & i \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & j \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image: 5 by 5 matrix with columns labeled a-e, and rows labeled f-j1]

as was posted by user Gonzalo Medina [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59519/225291). The Issue I am facing is importing the required packages to run this, as Google Colab will not run this as is when wrapped by either `$`'s or `$$`'s. How does one use `\usepackage` inside on Google Colab?

Comment: I fear that's a question for Google, not for us...

Comment: I think that Google Colab uses MathJaX so if you can figure out how to do it from MathJaX's syntax you might make some progress.  But MathJaX questions are off-topic here as it doesn't use TeX underneath but just simulates some of the LaTeX math input.

Comment: Realistically, Google is unlikely to reply (or provide support for a free product), but perhaps this TeX community has a solution, which will attract more readers to this good question/post. Solutions and workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For matrices specifically, this is what you do in Google Colab. You don't even need to `\usepackage` for this.

`$$\begin{matrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$`

This is what each of those look like, in order, depending on the style of brackets. This is a screenshot in Google Colab.

[image: Matrices]

If it's not included by default, then you can still get it. You don't want to use `\usepackage{something}`. Rather, you want to use something that works with MathJax specifically that goes along the lines of `\require{something}`.

For example, I was trying to use actuarial notation on Google Colab. What eventually worked for me, making things much more aesthetically pleasing, was `\require{enclose}`. This allowed me to then use `\enclose{actuarial}{somethingelse}`. I'm mainly saying this here because it took me a while to finally figure this out.