# Line breaking and floating

Tags: line-breaking, arrays

I have a matrix and I want to show some lines of text floating right to the matrix. The problem is that the following code shows two lines of text without executing `\\` break-line.

```
\[ M = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
a & b & c & d \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
a & b & c & d\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{array} \right)\ Something  \\ Something
]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what it is you want to write next to the matrix, you can always stack it in a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
    a & b & c & d \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    a & b & c & d\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \end{array} \right) \qquad
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
    First row \\ Row number 2 \\ Third row \\ Last or fourth row.
  \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Creating matrices is also somewhat automated using other constructions. See [Where is the `\matrix` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764) For example, your matrix could be created using a `pmatrix` environment.

Comment: Perfect: just another thing. Matrix is center aligned by default. How can I align it left?

Comment: @LatexNewbie: If you put your `array` inside `\[`...`\]` it will be centre aligned. If you don't want that, use `$`...`$`. If you're referring to the columns of the matrix, then you can simply change your column alignment specification from `cccc` to `llll` for `l`eft-aligned columns.