# How to draw the following table (simplex tableau)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, arrays

I would like to draw table,

[image: correct table]

I tried,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
z \\ 
s_1 \\
s_2 \\
s_3 
\end{array}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
  z & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & b \\ \hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1.6 & 2.2 & 0 & 544 \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0.4 & -0.2 & 0 & 16  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -0.2 & 0.6 & 0 & 72 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -0.4 & 0.2 & 1 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

However I get, with an allignment issue on the left,

[image: incorrect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as I posted the question i realized by adding another item in the first array I could move it down,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\\
z \\ 
s_1 \\
s_2 \\
s_3 
\end{array}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
  z & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & b \\ \hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1.6 & 2.2 & 0 & 544 \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0.4 & -0.2 & 0 & 16  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -0.2 & 0.6 & 0 & 72 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -0.4 & 0.2 & 1 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Is this the best method however?

Comment: It's a bit odd, in my opinion, to have the labels inside a matrix. I would advocate using [a `\kbordermatrix` to label the columns as well as rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/73121) instead.