# How to create elegant stripped regions in matrix along with numbering of the rows and columns

Tags: numbering, matrices

I want to create a matrix that will consist of regions with stripped lines (so as to denote that it is full banded) and other regions that will be all zero. I have seen some rows & columns numbering in other posts, but I find the size of the "numbers" is usually as big as the elements of the matrix itself, which is appalling. A preview of what I want to create is portrayed in the picture below.

[image]

I find it extremely difficult to create something like this, but I have understood by now that everything is possible in Latex, the point is to know how.

Comment: Can yo uinclude the bad output for us to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an adaptation of:

1. [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40059/4301) and
2. [Custom and built in TikZ fill patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns)

which achieves:

[image]

Note that you can overwrite existing entries with `fill=white` (as in the first example) or just leave them blank as in the second example.

### Notes:

- This does require two runs: the first to compute the positions of the box, and the second to draw it in the correct spot.
- Since this is using `tikz`, you automatically get all the flexibility inherent in `tikz`, such as line styles, line thickness, line color, fill, etc. These can be passed to the `\DrawBox` macro to customize each instance or provided as default options to maintain consistency.

### References:

- For matrix options refer to [Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=20pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north west lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[4][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[draw=gray,  #1]
      ($(#2)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
      ($(#3)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);
    \node at ($(#2)!0.5!(#3)$) {#4};
    }%
}



\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left[\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & \tikzmark{left 1}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\tikzmark{right 1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \tikzmark{left 2}           \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &                           \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &                           \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &                           \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &                           \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & & & & \tikzmark{right 2}
  \end{array}\right]
\]
\DrawBox[fill=white]{left 1}{right 1}{$\emptyset$}
\DrawBox[pattern=custom north west lines,]{left 2}{right 2}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one but using empty set for zero matrix is really really strange :)

Comment: @percusse: Yep, but that is what the OP showed in the image.