# Why "p" in pmatrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I am using the command `\begin{pmatrix} [...] \end{pmatrix}`. I wonder why this command is not just called `\begin{matrix} [...] \end{matrix}` and why a "p" before "matrix".

Comment: "p" for "parenthesis", the surrounding delimiter.  One might surmise that `bmatrix` is for bracketed matrices.

Comment: The `matrix` environment is the generic version -- it has no delimiters.

Comment: `B` for braces, `V` for vertical bars and there are more.

Comment: And `B` for “braces”, `v` for “vert” (like in `\vert`), `V` for “Vert” (like in `\Vert`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: You were the first who commented -- would you write the answer as an anthology on `matrix` delimiters? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can do it also! (if Steven does not do it)

Comment: @Colas: Only if Steven doesn't write it -- 'grace period' -- I am waiting

Comment: Related: [Where is the \matrix command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides a number of options.  The leading letter before `matrix` indicates the delimiter that is used:

`p` for parens, `b` for brackets, `v` for verts, `B` for braces, `V` for double verts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{matrix}
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{vmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{vmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{Bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{Vmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{Vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Plain TeX defines the macro `\pmatrix` as matrix with parentheses and `\matrix` as the same without parentheses. So, the terminology mentioned here is inspired by plain TeX.

Answer (score -1):

The "*p*" in `pmatrix` stands for "*parentheses*"

There is also `Bmatrix` for "*Brace Matrix*"

and... `bmatrix` for "*bracket Matrix*"

[image: picture of various matricies]

Comment: All this is already mentioned in the @Steven B. Segletes answer, from where is also showed image ...