# How to Write Arrays of Arbitrary Formats Without Latex

Tags: matrices

I need to write an array in the form of the photo below

[image]

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "arbitrary formats"?

Comment: By "without LaTeX", do you mean "in plain Tex"?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you mean "without Latex"? this site is designated to use `latex` and friends ...

Comment: In case you still want to use LaTeX, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/47927

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than just plain TeX, you can input `eplain`, so also adding support for color.

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{color}
\endpackages

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{191,19,18}

$$
\left[\matrix{
  \textcolor{myred}{A_{11}} & A_{12} & A_{13} & \dots & A_{1n} \cr
  A_{21} & \textcolor{myred}{A_{22}} & A_{23} & \dots & A_{2n} \cr
  A_{31} & A_{32} & \textcolor{myred}{A_{33}} & \dots & A_{3n} \cr
  A_{41} & A_{42} & A_{43} & \dots & A_{4n} \cr
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
  A_{n1} & A_{n2} & A_{n3} & \dots & \textcolor{myred}{A_{nn}} \cr
}\right]
$$

\bye
```

[image]

The same with `opmac`:

```
\input opmac

\def\myred{\localcolor\setcmykcolor{0 0.9 0.9 0.25}}

$$
\left[\matrix{
  \myred A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & \dots & A_{1n} \cr
  A_{21} & \myred A_{22} & A_{23} & \dots & A_{2n} \cr
  A_{31} & A_{32} & \myred A_{33} & \dots & A_{3n} \cr
  A_{41} & A_{42} & A_{43} & \dots & A_{4n} \cr
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
  A_{n1} & A_{n2} & A_{n3} & \dots & \myred A_{nn} \cr
}\right]
$$

\bye
```