# How to align words outside matrix?

Tags: align, matrices, mathjax

It is difficult to describe my question, so I give the picture which shows the difficults:

[image]

Some words are outside of the matrix, both rows and columns. How to align them?

It is better to have solution in MathJax, not only in Latex.

Thanks for help!

John

Comment: MathJax is off-topic.  In LaTeX you can use [`kbordermatrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). See [Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/4301) for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MathJax is off-topic on this site, but in LaTeX you can use [`kbordermatrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix).  Download the `kbordermatrix.sty` file from the provided link and place it in the same directory as your document.  Then you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[
  \newcommand\col[1]{\parbox{1cm}{\centering\scriptsize#1}}
  \omega(\mu\nu|\theta) =
  \kbordermatrix{
                       &        & \col{$\mu$th column} &        & \col{$\nu$th column} &        \\
                       &        & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        \\
    \text{$\mu$th row} & \cdots & \cos\theta           & \cdots & \sin\theta           & \cdots \\
                       &        & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        \\
    \text{$\nu$th row} & \cdots & -\sin\theta          & \cdots & \cos\theta           & \cdots \\
                       &        & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        \\
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using `blkarray` for more flexibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
  \newcommand\col[1]{\parbox{1cm}{\centering\scriptsize#1}}
  \newcommand\row[1]{\text{\scriptsize#1}}
  \omega(\mu\nu|\theta) =
  \begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
           & \col{$\mu$th column} &        & \col{$\nu$th column} &        &                   \\
  \begin{block}{[ccccc]c}
           & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        &                   \\
    \cdots & \cos\theta           & \cdots & \sin\theta           & \cdots & \row{$\mu$th row} \\
           & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        &                   \\
    \cdots & -\sin\theta          & \cdots & \cos\theta           & \cdots & \row{$\nu$th row} \\
           & \vdots               &        & \vdots               &        &                   \\
  \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In MathJax you can screw around with some manual positioning to piece together something that looks sort of right.  Of course this will break when you change the font or the font size.

```
$$
  \omega(\mu\nu|\theta) =
  \left[
  \matrix{
           & \vdots      &        & \vdots     &        \\
    \cdots & \cos\theta  & \cdots & \sin\theta & \cdots \\
           & \vdots      &        & \vdots     &        \\
    \cdots & -\sin\theta & \cdots & \cos\theta & \cdots \\
           & \vdots      &        & \vdots     &        \\
  }
  \right]
  \matrix{
    \phantom{\vdots} \\
    \text{$\mu$th row} \\
    \phantom{\vdots} \\
    \text{$\nu$th row} \\
    \phantom{\vdots} \\
  }
  \hskip-14.3em\raise 13ex \hbox{$\mu$th}\hskip-2.5em\raise 10ex \hbox{column}
  \hskip 3.5em\raise 13ex \hbox{$\nu$th}\hskip-2.5em\raise 10ex \hbox{column}
$$
```

[image]

<kbd>[Live example](http://mathb.in/36180)</kbd>