# How to label lines and columns of a matrix?

Tags: tables, matrices, displaystyle

How can I obtain the following representation?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a `\bordermatrix` (see for example [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/52406)?

Comment: The `nicematrix` package does this well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a job for `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
& C & D \\
C & b-c & -c \\
D & b & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]